# How to Run vnc4server on Ubuntu in Certain Resolution?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, vnc, resolution

There's a headless Ubuntu instance used as a host for our build server. I have some UI code that requires some graphical output. [Installing a vnc4server](http://www.ehow.com/how_5089245_install-vnc-server-ubuntu.html) and [redirecting a DISPLAY to it](http://osi.fotap.org/2008/10/29/running-an-x-server-during-a-bamboo-or-other-sort-of-automated-build/) worked like a charm. Not that my UI tests are running but test scripts can take screen shots.

Problem is that I need to set the resolution that vnc4server uses to serve the graphical content. Does anybody know how to configure it on Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

http://usingnix.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/setup-vnc-in-ubuntu-10-10/
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Remote_Access_to_the_Ubuntu_Linux_Desktop